# Como inserir dados para elaboração de grafico no ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quero fazer um gráfico de linhas com o ggplot, porém aparece esta mensagem:

> **Error:** Don't know how to add geom_point to a plot

Segue o modelo com estou fazendo:

```
a<-c(4.9, 4.4, 4.2, 3.9, 3.7, 3.5, 3.1, 3, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 2.7, 2.6, 2.5)
b<-c(0.97, 1.13, 1.19, 1.14, 1.16, 1.25, 1.24, 1.46, 1.62, 1.94, 1.36, 1.91, 1.8, 1.89)
Ano<-c(1999:2012)
dados<-data.frame(a,b,Ano)
ggplot(dados, aes(x=Ano,y=a))
+geom_point
```

Answer (score 3):

Faltou apenas colocar os parênteses depois de `geom_point`, já que `geom_point` é uma função que você deve chamar:

```r
ggplot(dados, aes(x=Ano,y=a)) + geom_point()
```